# PHP Syntax Explanation for "and" keyword

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I was looking at the Laravel 3 source code, and I saw a weird syntax in the `larave/section.php` file:

```
ob_start() and static::$last[] = $section;
```

What is this weird assignment syntax? How do you read it? Does it mean that we're assining `$section` to `static::$last[]` if `ob_start()` returns `true`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is a shorthand for

```
if (ob_start()) { static::$last[] = $section; }
```

due to short-circuit nature of boolean operators.